# Serial Port Reading with Processing, cannot find the string

Tags: arduino, serial-port, processing

I am trying to read serial port from Processing. In that purpose I am trying basic hello world example. I write Hello world! from Arduino and try to catch it with Processing. Here are the codes:

Here is the code for Arduino Uno:

```
void setup() 
{
  //initialize serial communications at a 9600 baud rate
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  //send 'Hello, world!' over the serial port
  Serial.println("Hello, world!");
  //wait 100 milliseconds so we don't drive ourselves crazy
  delay(100);
}
```

Here is the code for Processing:

```
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;  // Create object from Serial class

String val;     // Data received from the serial port
String check     = "Hello, world!";
String portName  = Serial.list()[1]; //COM4



void setup() {
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
  println("Starting Serial Read Operation");
}

void draw()
{

  if ( myPort.available() > 0) {  // If data is available,


    val = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');


    println(val);
    if (val != null && val.equals("Hello, world!") == true) {

      println("Found the starting Point");
    }
  }
}
```

I cannot catch the check string.

Output of the Processing :

```
null
Hello, world!

null
Hello, world!

null
Hello, world!

Hello, world!
```

According to the output, I can successfully read the serial port. (However there are many nulls, I don't know why.) But I cannot catch the specified string.

Do you have an idea what the problem can be?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Arduino sends `\r\n` when using println.

When you compare, it fails as you are comparing `"Hello, world!\r"` with `"Hello, world!"`.

You can solve this by using `Serial.print()` and manually adding an `\n` to your strings or sending a `Serial.write('\n');` after your text (repetition can be replaced with a helper function).